# Nodejs with macOS: # Fatal error in , line 0 - gatsby develop

Tags: node.js, macos, gatsby

I am using gatsby cli, Suddenly **gatsby develop** command returning an error even if I create new site from scratch. I am using M1 macbook pro with big sur, is there anyone faced same issue? if yes how to resolve this?. I have configured everything properly by following official doc, am I missing something?
[here is my terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c13N.png)

Error:
macOS 11.2: Fatal error `Check failed: allocator->SetPermissions`

Parts of the stacktrace:

```sh
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: allocator->SetPermissions(reinterpret_cast<void*>(region.begin()), region.size(), PageAllocator::kNoAccess).
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x16f986408
 1: 0x100575758 node::NodePlatform::GetStackTracePrinter()::$_3::__invoke() 
...
```

Comment: Currently, this issue is going with the current latest node version
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/37061
Please revert back your node version to make it work for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a Node-related issue. According to [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/37061), try:

```
arch -x86_64 zsh

nvm install 14
nvm alias default 14
exit
```

All the solutions are related to the Node version. Remember to clean your cache by running `gatsby clean` and removing the `node_modules` in each trial.

As other [threads points](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/37061) the issue seems to be related to the latest Node version. With the snippet above you'll roll back to version 14 as a temporal workaround while the issue is being fixed.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your answer. How to apply these commands as I installed node via homebrew? I think there is different procedure for homebrew?

Comment: You need to install the Node Version Manager (NVM, https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)  and run the `nvm install 14`, `nvm alias default 14`/`nvm use 14`

Comment: Did the same but now its returning: 
`
17: 0x104ee1db8 v8::internal::Compiler::Compile(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Compiler::ClearExceptionFlag, v8::internal::IsCompiledScope*) [/Users/musharof/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
18: 0x1052885c8 v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/musharof/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
19: 0x1055a5eac 
.......
zsh: abort      gatsby develop
`

Comment: have you removed your node_modules, your package-lock.json and have reinstalled it?

Comment: Yes, I did. Even all the node/gatsby related command no working and returning zsh: abort. Here is the screenshot to my terminal: [link] https://imgur.com/XdilMdI Thanks a lot for your answers <3

Comment: No, only NPM. I will try and let you guys know. Thanks

Comment: It worked! after changing the terminal into iterm, haha. Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

[This was fixed in Node v15.9.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/37061#issuecomment-780499544) If you installled using homebrew on a mac you can do `brew upgrade node` to get the latest version

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately the only solution is to revert to **nodejs 14**, using Rosetta.

Additional here's the issue in V8: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=11389

> No ETA. Everyone, please stop asking for when this will be resolved.
> We know about the issue and are working on it.
>
> Also note that Node.js is still not officially supported on
> macOS+arm64. We do not produce binaries for it and you can use the x64
> ones in the mean time.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/37061#issuecomment-772559363

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this issue by reinstalling node via nvm.

I had to open Rosetta 2 Terminal first.

nvm install node

nvm use node

After these commands.

I reinstalled packages using yarn command.

this way it worked.

Answer (score -1):

This works... `nvm install 16`

Here's the nvm install docs... https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm